# Is it possible to to deploy a smart-contract written in Solidity, on Solana?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, rust

Hope you all are doing great, I code in Solidity and now I have this requirement to convert **Solidity** code into **Rust** for **Solana**.
While figuring out a way I came across with **Solang**. I'm looking for suggestions on this.

While coding in solidity and using Solang like how much freedom would I have with Solang for Solana, or should I go for Solang or rather code in Rust?

**P.S: A friend of mine thinks it's not supported on mainnet, just for testnets as of yet. Is he right?**

TIA for your suggestions.
Have a good one!

Answer (score 1):

[Solana has its own EVM compatible virtual machine called Neon EVM](https://neon-labs.org/). However it is not ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Solana is a new blockchain focusing on performance. It supports smart
> contracts like Ethereum which they call Programs. You can develop
> those in Rust, but there's also a new project now to compile Solidity
> to Solana. In other words you can deploy your contracts written in
> Solidity now to Solana!

https://soliditydeveloper.com/solana

Comment: are there any limitations? I mean do you have full independence on creating smart-contract in Solidity for Solana or somewhere you have to use Rust insted?